# jQuery - Get the value of unselected item in multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

Although this may sound dead simple, the matter is complicated by the fact I can only use the  change() trigger on the select element. I am using the 'Chosen' jQuery plugin which basically modifies the multi select box on the page.

Whenever a item is selected or unselected, the plugin triggers the change event on the original select element. I am obviously able to get all the unselected items, but I need the one that was just unselected that caused the change event to trigger.

So I have the following function, the bit in the middle is what I need to capture the item that was just unselected. #cho is the id of the original select element.

```
$("#cho").chosen().change( function() {

// Need code here to capture what item was just unselected, if any...

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Use hidden field

2.Hidden field value initially empty.

3.Onchange put the selected value in a hidden field.

4.If onchange is happening again , hidden field value is the previously selected value.

```
$("#cho").chosen().change( function() {

 var hidvalue =  $('#hiddenfield').val();
 if (hidvalue ) {
   //Get the previously selected ids
    var prev_ids = $('#hiddenfield').val();
   //Then Update currently selected ids  
    $('#hiddenfield').val('currently selected ids');
 } else {
     //Update currently selected ids  
    $('#hiddenfield').val('currently selected ids');  
 }

})
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean here? You understand that this is a multi select element?

Comment: Ah, I understand. I like this idea. I wonder if it might be better to store values directly in a variable, will probably be easier to compare previous values with the updated values to see what's missing....... edit: Just realised this is pretty much exactly what slacker said in the answer below.

Comment: You can use it in your own way  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Store value when the user changes the the check box.

var preVal;

$("input[name='g']").on("change",function(e){
    if(preVal){

```
    alert(preVal);
}

preVal=$(this).val();
```

});

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/fcpfm/

Answer (score 1):

Try using a variable to store the selected item. Update it each time when item changed. I cant add comment. That is why I am posting it as an answer.